# Can we use loops to execute a query in pyspark

Tags: python, sql, pyspark, error-handling, databricks

```
`Table_names=[EMP_ID,EMP_NAME,EMP_ADD,EMP_PHNO]
for i in Table_nams:
    spark.sql("select * from Employee where i is null")'
```

Getting an error saying cannot resolve 'i'

Answer (score 0):

you need to generate the sql query first before passing it to spark.sql

also you need to pass the values in `'` since the values are string type

```
Table_names=['EMP_ID','EMP_NAME','EMP_ADD','EMP_PHNO']
for i in Table_names:
    sql_query =  "select * from Employee where " +i+" is null"
    spark.sql(sql_query)
```